# Parameterize Tangent Line to Level Curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $$f(x, y) = x^2y + yx - xy^2$$
>
> Find a parameterization of the tangent line to the level curve of $f$ through the point $(1, 1)$.

---

I have already computed the gradient of $f$ and found the critical points.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1, 1), \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1, 1) \right)$ is normal to the level curve. Then the vector $\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1, 1), \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,1) \right)$ is tangent to the level curve. I just rotated the gradient by $90 $ degrees counterclockwise. Then your line is: $${\bf X}(t) = (1,1)+ t \left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1, 1), \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,1) \right), \quad t\in \Bbb R.$$